# Multiple SQL count requests, one query

Tags: mysql

I'm brand new to SQL and I know this should be easy, but I can't seem to find any reference on how to do specifically what I'm looking for.  I've check the archives and I can't find a basic example.

Anyway, all I want is -

```
SELECT
(COUNT (i.productNumber WHERE i.type = 'type1') AS 'Type 1'),
(COUNT (i.productNumber WHERE i.type = 'type2') AS 'Type 2'),
FROM items AS i 
WHERE i.dateadded BETWEEN '2015-03-02' and '2015-03-04'
```

The two count conditions are different, but both of those queries share that date condition.  I've done two distinct select statements and put a UNION between them.  That works.  The only issue is all of the data appears in one column under the first alias in the statement.  I would need each alias to be a new column.  I also have to write the date condition in twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group them by type so you would get a different row for each of them :

```
SELECT i.type, COUNT(i.productNumber)
FROM items i
WHERE i.dateadded BETWEEN '2015-03-02' AND '2015-03-04'
GROUP BY i.type;
```

If you really want to have one row, then you could do

```
SELECT COUNT(b.productNumber) AS 'type1', COUNT(c.productNumber) AS 'type2'
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN items b on b.productNumber = i.productNumber
LEFT JOIN items c on c.productNumber = i.productNumber
WHERE i.dateadded BETWEEN '2015-03-02' AND '2015-03-04'
  AND b.type = 'type1'
  AND c.type = 'type2';
```

Comment: I should have been more specific.  The types are actually on an "IN" statement so figure a count by i.type IN ('CAR','BOAT', 'TRACTOR'), etc. another count for i.type ('PLANE','HELICOPTER'), etc.  Looking at the second option you gave, however, I'm guessing I could just replace the conditional with those IN statements.  Am I correct in assuming that?

Comment: I played around with it.  I've got it working pretty close to how I want it to.  Thanks for your help!